# how to show wordcloud image on dash web application

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I need to render a wordcloud on my dash application. According to this thread https://community.plot.ly/t/solved-is-it-possible-to-make-a-wordcloud-in-dash/4565, there is no wordcloud build-in component in dash. One workaround is to use `WordCloud` module to produce the wordcloud as image and use `dash_html_components.Img` to show on layout.

I'm new to Dash. Not sure how I can render the image. Do I need to save wordcloud as temp image everytime I produce a wordcloud?

Really appreciate it if anyone with some expertise in Dash can help with that.

The code is below:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

print(dcc.__version__) # 0.6.0 or above is required

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

dfm = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'], 'freq': [1,3,9]})

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Img(id = 'image_wc')
])

# function to make wordcoud from word frequency dataframe
def plot_wordcloud (data):
        d = {}
        for a, x in data.values:
            d[a] = x
        wc = WordCloud(background_color='black',
                    width=1800,
                    height=1400).generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=d)   
        return (wc)

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('image_wc', 'img'))
def make_image ():
    img = plot_wordcloud (data = dfm)
    return (img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a working example below. It uses the `pip`-installable `wordcloud` library, and passes a base-64 encoded PNG representation of the resulting image through `BytesIO` so you don't need to dump all the created PNG files each time.

I've got it triggering off of itself so that it'll run when you load the Dash app, though you could have it work dynamically off of a button or similar.

```
import dash
import dash.dependencies as dd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import base64

# external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__) #, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

dfm = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'], 'freq': [1,3,9]})

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Img(id="image_wc"),
])

def plot_wordcloud(data):
    d = {a: x for a, x in data.values}
    wc = WordCloud(background_color='black', width=480, height=360)
    wc.fit_words(d)
    return wc.to_image()

@app.callback(dd.Output('image_wc', 'src'), [dd.Input('image_wc', 'id')])
def make_image(b):
    img = BytesIO()
    plot_wordcloud(data=dfm).save(img, format='PNG')
    return 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Super thanks. this works!  I will be able to award points in a couple of hours.

Comment: would you mind explain a little bit how it works?   In `dd.Input('image_wc', 'id')`, why the value is `id`?  why `make_image` need a parameter like `b`? Also, `'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode())` is confusing to me.   @Randy

Comment: Sure thing. 1) The `dd.Input` is really just a filler to make sure that the callback triggers. Normally, you'd put something meaningful in there so that when you typed something in a box or clicked a button or something, the callback would rerun. Since I only want it to run once, it's set to run whenever the `id` of `image_wc` changes, which only happens when the page is created. It passes the inputs as a parameter to the function, which is why that `b` is there and never used.

Comment: 2) For HTML `<img>` tags, the normal use of `src` is to set it to a location to display. You can actually embed the entire image in the `src` field as base64 encoded text though with that `data:image...` syntax. The image was piped into the `BytesIO` `img`, so first `.getvalue()` retrieves the byte representation, `b64encode` translates the bytes to printable characters, and `decode()` translates the bytes to a Python string.

Comment: @Randy Here's hoping you're still active. Your answer here has saved me. However, there is one part I can't figure out. make_image() is never called anywhere, how is it doing anything?

Comment: @MPJ567 Dash works off of triggered callbacks, which are set using that @app.callback decorator. The first argument gives the thing that should be updated (in this case, `src` of image_wc), and the second gives all of the different things that should trigger a call to `make_image()` (in this case, just when the ID of the image_wc gets set, which only happens once when the page is loaded).

Comment: @Randy thanks much for answering! So, although there is no explicit call to make_image(), it is actually called at run time because it sits below the callback?

Comment: @MPJ567 Yep. Some part of `app.run_server()` eventually ends up triggering calls to `make_image()`